# read.csv.chunked not working with filter %in% list or is.element in list in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have a large file (>6GB) with 5million+ rows and 329 columns.

Need to pull out full records for 23k rows for a fixed list of Health Care Providers (HCPlist$NPI).  Trying to subset or filter by chunks during read as file size overloads my 14GB RAM.

Initially had trouble due to data type so I have already converted HCPlist$NPI to integer to match data type in source file.

Tried the following and both ran smoothly but came up with 0 rows and 329 columns (ie no records)

```
f <- function(x, pos) filter(x, x[,1] %in% HCPlist$NPI)
NPPESinfo_list <- read_csv_chunked("npidata_pfile_20050523-20190210.csv", 
    DataFrameCallback$new(f), chunk_size = 10000)
```

Also tried `subset` instead of `filter` as well as the following...also all ran smoothly but output was 0 rows and 329 columns (ie again no records)

```
# Filter NPPES Data for NPIs
f <- function(x, pos) x[(is.element(x[,1], HCPlist$NPI)),]  
NPPESinfo_list <- read_csv_chunked("npidata_pfile_20050523-20190210.csv", 
    DataFrameCallback$new(f), chunk_size = 10000)
```

I have run similar code in the past filtering specific specialty codes and it has run fine.  For example...

```
# Filter NPPES Data for Specialty (Medical Oncologists = "207RX0202X")
f2 <- function(x, pos) subset(x,
    x[,48] == "207RX0202X" |
    x[,52] == "207RX0202X" )
NPIs_MedOnc <- read_csv_chunked("npidata_pfile_20050523-20190210.csv", 
    DataFrameCallback$new(f2), chunk_size = 10000)
```

When I run the same filter above only against the first 2000 rows of the file it runs fine.

```
# Test run on first 2000 rows
df <- read.csv(file="npidata_pfile_20050523-20190210.csv",nrows=2000)
df2 <- filter(df, df[,1] %in% HCPlist$NPI)
```

I get a nice dataframe with 48 rows and 329 columns.

Not sure why `filter` with `%in%` works fine on just the first 2000 rows and gives me 48 records.  However when part of a function and applied to `read.csv.chunked` it gives me no records?

Could use some help here as I haven't found a similar case/question elsewhere on Stackoverflow or google.

The parts seem to work fine but when I put what I want together not getting the needed records.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'am not sure if this is the answer, but I tried some stuff with the `mtcars` dataset.
I try to only select the cars with 3 gears.

This works:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)

f1 <- function(x, pos) filter(x, gear %in% c(3))
read_csv_chunked(readr_example("mtcars.csv"), DataFrameCallback$new(f1), chunk_size = 5)
```

And this also works, just like you showed:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)

my_df <- read.csv(readr_example("mtcars.csv"), nrows = 5)
my_df2 <- filter(my_df, my_df[, 10] %in% c(3))
```

But this gives me 0 rows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)

f2 <- function(x, pos) filter(x, x[, 10] %in% c(3))
read_csv_chunked(readr_example("mtcars.csv"), DataFrameCallback$new(f2), chunk_size = 5)
```

I don't now why (yet) this behaves like this, but the trick seems to use the column name in your function `f`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ricoderks!!!  Great insight for a simple but effective fix!!!

For some reason `read.csv.chunked` did not like having the variable identified by the column number indicator in the function (ie. `x[, 10]`), even though this same function worked great separately.  Not sure why...

Simplest solution worked best!

Just replaced `x[, 10]` with the name of the column/variable `NPI`.  Did not even include the name of the dataframe as it is already specified as part of `filter` function, and it worked like a charm!

More specifically...replaced this...

```
f <- function(x, pos) filter(x, x[,1] %in% HCPlist$NPI)
NPPESinfo_list <- read_csv_chunked("npidata_pfile_20050523-20190210.csv", 
    DataFrameCallback$new(f), chunk_size = 10000)
```

...with this...

```
f <- function(x, pos) filter(x, NPI %in% HCPlist$NPI)
NPPESinfo_list <- read_csv_chunked("npidata_pfile_20050523-20190210.csv", 
    DataFrameCallback$new(f), chunk_size = 10000)
```

Worked perfectly!!!

Thanks again!!!